# Какие способы компиляции существуют в python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

Хочу скомпилировать свою программу в исполняемый файл .exe но столкнулся с проблемой при компиляции через pyinstaller нельзя вставить тест через правую кнопку мыши окно тупо не появляеться а через cx_freeze создается целая папка а мне нужно единственный файл. Что посоветуете?

Comment: что значит: `нельзя вставить тест через правую кнопку мыши окно тупо не появляеться` ?

Comment: @S. Nick значит то что в обычной консоли я могу через правую кнопку мыши нажать "вставить" а в скомпилированном варианте такое не сделаешь

Comment: Понял, шелл урезанный)

Comment: нет там компиляции. это упаковка всего что нужно включая интерпретатор в exe файл.

Comment: Python - интерпретируемый язык программирования, его не принято компилировать, он предназначен для другого и раскрывается он в другом. Не нужно пытаться забить саморез молотком, когда он должен вкручиваться. Хочешь компилировать - есть С, GO и прочее